# Nivo slider is acting weird with fadeIn() jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

The basic structure (VERY dumbed down) of the page is something like:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="nivo">
nivo slider here
</div></div>
```

I'm trying to animate the #content div with something like:

```
$('#content').hide().delay(1500).fadeIn();
```

It works and all, but afterwards, the Nivo slider does some weird stuff and flashes white everytime it loads a new image.

Anyone know what's wrong? It's running on a wordpress theme so the page structure is kind of rigid so I don't think I can do any extensive modifications to the .php files (i.e. the nivo  will always be inside the content ).

Answer (score -1):

In which browser do you see this behavior?

I've just went to the nivo site on Chrome, used the jQueryfy bookmarlet and ran this line on the console

```
$("header").hide().delay(1500).fadeIn()
```

And after all the slider appears and shows the images as expected. Maybe you should trim down the css code around those elements of yours, in order to detect the defect.